# How can I detrigger an aggro?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So I was on the mission One For my Baby, where  you have to find the suspect in Novac who sold a woman to slavery.

I made the mistake towards the end to unlock the safe WHEN Jeanne May Crawford was there.  Now, everytime I load the save, she attacks me.

What's worst is that I have both Veronica and ED-E as companions, and I only have a split second to get out of the lobby (where the save is) or else she'll die to my companions

I was thinking there's a console command to detrigger an aggro, but I don't know how to get rid of this.

Is there a set time I need to be gone to reset her aggro? Or is it inevitable that she dies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the console to `disable` then `enable` her she should be non-aggressive after respawning.  You can also try `tai` to disable her AI.  Just keep in mind for FNV, using a console command will lock you out of getting achievements for that session.

Comment: So there's virtually no way to not lock the achievments up?

Comment: @Retrosaur just restart the game and you can earn achievements again